# Camera Preview: No errors but no picture :-(

Tags: android, camera

Have read the books and hints, got rid of all compile errors and warnings and put in some debug statements.

```
package com.cit.BroadcastSim;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class BroadcastActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
  public Camera myCamera;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.broadcast);  // Inflate the broadcast.xml file

    Log.d("BROADCAST", "Creating the Activity");
    SurfaceView cameraSurface = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camerasurface);
    SurfaceHolder cameraHolder = cameraSurface.getHolder();
    cameraHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    cameraHolder.addCallback(this);
    Log.d("BROADCAST", "Now wait for some CallBacks");
}


  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Surface created, now it is possible to set the preview
    Log.d("BROADCAST", "Surface Created");
    try {
      Log.d("BROADCAST","CAMERA: NOT NULL");
      myCamera = Camera.open();
      myCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
      myCamera.startPreview();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("BROADCAST", e.getMessage());
      }
  }

  public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d("BROADCAST", "Surface Destroyed");
    myCamera.stopPreview();
    myCamera.release();
  }

  public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int I, int J, int K) {
    Log.d("BROADCAST", "Surface Changed");
    myCamera.stopPreview();
    myCamera.release();
  }
}
```

In the DDMS debugger, I get a log message for 'Creating the Activity' followed by 'Now wait for some CallBacks' and nothing more in terms of my Debug messages so I think Callback is not working - for the life of me can't see where I have got it wrong.

In the manifest I have

The Activity XML page has

```
<TextView  
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:text="@string/Broadcast"
  />
<SurfaceView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/camerasurface" 
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, on the Android phone (HTC Wildfire), the page loads, the textView message appears at the top left and that is all.

Should mention that I am very new to this platform and accept that I might have missed something very very basic.

Any ideas/comments will be very much appreciated,

Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

haven't got enough time to explain (meeting with friends in a few minutes). I basically added some functions into "surfaceChanged()" (this is where you should start the preview).

Therefore you don't need mCam.startPreview() in "surfaceCreated()"

```
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Surface created, now it is possible to set the preview
    Log.d("BROADCAST", "Surface Created");
    try {
      Log.d("BROADCAST","CAMERA: NOT NULL");
      mCam = Camera.open();
      mCam.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
      //myCamera.startPreview();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("BROADCAST", e.getMessage());
      }
  }

  public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d("BROADCAST", "Surface Destroyed");
    mCam.stopPreview();
    mCam.release();
  }

  public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int I, int J, int K) {
      Camera.Parameters parameters = mCam.getParameters();
    List<Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Size bestSize = null;
    int bestDiff = 0;
    int diff = 0;
    for (Size size : previewSizes) {
            diff = Math.abs(K - size.height) + Math.abs(J - size.width);
        if (bestSize == null || diff < bestDiff) {
                bestSize = size;
                bestDiff = diff;
        }
        parameters.setPreviewSize(bestSize.width, bestSize.height);
        mCam.setParameters(parameters);
    }

    //start preview of camera
      mCam.startPreview();
  }
```

xml-file (you did a little copy & paste error)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
```

Hope I could help :)
I think, via setting the orientation, you could change the camera picture to portrait mode. :) (it's landscape right now)

Comment: Hi, had managed to sort out seom of my problems - basically closing everything in the SurfaceChanged() but your soilution is quite nifty.  Will spend this evening going through it to make sure I understand it properly and will then implement it.  Intend setting the camera in portrait view as it is part of an experiment in human interaction.  Much appreciate your feedback, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the ApiDemos (Graphics->CameraPreview) and the class CameraPreview. That was what I did (all the ApiDemos are great btw) and it worked like a charm. It's good to have something working first - you can then strip it off the stuff you don't need in your app. The demo is also online here: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html. Hope that helped.

Comment: Couldnt agree with you more, there is a lot to be said in having something working first and not be looking at blank screens of, worse still, loads of small red Xs in the source code.  Had a quick peek at the sample code, dont know how I missed it before - it is very comprehensive and takes care of situations that I would never have thought about.  Plenty more learning required and thanks a lot of the pointer in teh right direction, much appreciated.  Oliver

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I think that whole camera preview handling "by hand" is overly complex.
If you just want to take a picture and have a preview first, you can tell this the system via an Intent. I've written a post about this some time ago http://javablogs.com/Jump.action?id=618025
Basically it goes:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

And then within your activity you can get the data in a `onActivityResult()` callback

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if(requestCode==1&& resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
  }
}
```

If you need a larger image than the default, have a look at [MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_OUTPUT).